# An interface with different method parameters

Tags: java, class, interface

I want to declare an interface be use with several classes
this classes have method with different parameters

interface:

```
public interface Operation {

public int Add();

}
```

class A:

```
public class CLASSA implement Operation{

     public int Add(int id,String name);

}
```

class B:

```
public class CLASSB implement Operation{

     public int Add(String name);

}
```

how to impelement of this interface?

Comment: If they have different parameters, then they're not using the same interface!

Comment: I don't think there's an appropriate answer for this question as that's no the right usage of interfaces. But if your provide information, why you want to do that, there may be another approach to solve your problem.

Comment: As it stands, this can't be answered in a sensible manner.  Please describe **why** you need to do this (i.e. how you intend to use this hypothetical interface).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you could make an operand-object

```
public interface Operation {

public int Add(Operand o);

}
```

or

```
public interface Operation {

 public int Add(Operand... o);

}
```

Comment: now you can use this interface
and simulate different arguments

there is no other way to do this, because otherwise, you would need different interfaces

Comment: This gives flexibility but needs extra type checking, but this may be a necessary tradeoff in some situations so it's a useful solution imo. It also means you could subclass Operand and add logic for this subclass in an implementation of the interface, allowing any type of arguments to be passed. Note however that `Operands` should read `Operand` if that is indeed the name of the class.

Answer (score 9):

A few points worth mentioning regarding the other answers:

- Having and interface with multiple function implementation (one for each set of arguments) violates the [interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).
- Making the class ignore the unused arguments violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

My suggestion would be to implement something like the [Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern. To decouple the command implementation from its implementations is precisely its intent.

Comment: link expired but quick google for command pattern should be enough

Comment: wikipedia for the lazy people: [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to declare the parameter as a field in the class. Now pass it as a parameter to the constructor, so now it is specified when a new instance of the class is created.

Answer (score 1):

in this case you are not using the same interface, but you can create an hereditary system in which some parameters are automatically inserted:

```
public class CLASSA{
     public int Add(int id,String name){
         //something
     }
}

public class CLASSB extends CLASSA{
     public int Add(String name){
         super.Add(this.FIXED_ID, name);
         //something
     }
}

public class OPERATION extends CLASSA{
     public int Add(){
         super.Add(this.FIXED_ID, this.FIXED_NAME);
         //something
     }
}
```

Comment: Note however that it's generally better to add extra details within subclasses and not take them away, since any modifications will result in less maintenance required.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions
Either define two methods in the interface:

```
public interface Operation {

public int addName(String name);
public int addIdName(int id, String name);

}
```

or use a generic paramter

```
public interface Operation {

    public int add(HashMap<String,String> keyValueParams);
}
```

But for Operations this should work different.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do like this.  If the interface Operations is yours (not predefined or somebody else), have overloaded abstract methods in it.  This is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Best to try it out:

```
public interface Operation {
    public int add();
}


public class SimpleOperation implements Operation {

    @Override
    public int add() {
        return 0;
    }

    public int add(int id, String name) {
        return id;
    }

}
```

When in use:

```
Operation op = new SimpleOperation();
op.add(); // Valid
op.add(2, "two"); // Invalid
```

Basically, although you're able to add that method into the class, if it doesn't exist in the interface then you can't call it if the instance you're calling it on is of that interface.

This is valid however, since the instance is of class `SimpleOperation`, which has the overloaded method declared:

```
SimpleOperation op = new SimpleOperation();
op.add(); // Valid
op.add(2, "two"); // Also valid
```

This reduces the usefulness of an interface however. If you're keen on overloading the methods, consider using an abstract superclass with both the methods defined and override them in your subclass. Or, add both the original and overloaded method into the interface.

Comment: but now, your interface us useless, 
because Add(int,String) is not defined in here...

also, java-convention tells you to use lowercase method names add()

Comment: @cIph3r you're absolutely right, hadn't noticed. OP should also not use full caps on the class name.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea, it violates OO design and the idea behind an interface. An interface is supposed to be used as a way to abstract away the method calls from the implementation.

My recommendation is to use the method with both parameters in the interface and just don't use the ID argument in CLASSB or to not have an add method in the interface and just have different versions in each class.